# Is it possible to get a warning when using a global variable in a function without expicitely passing it to the function?

Tags: python

In python if you define a global variable it's known to all functions without explicit passing and you can do e.g. this:

```
x=1
def func():
    return x
```

I know this is normal behaviour, but it's also enabling unclean code because the interpreter doesn't tell you if you forget to pass a global variable to a function.

I'm usually writing scripts for data processing where usually all the code is in one file as data processing is a linear process. For the same reason I only use functions but not classes. However that way of designing leads to having lots of global variables and sometimes forgetting to pass all of them explicitely to functions.

Is there a way to have Python throw a warning when I use a global variable in a function without explicitely passing it?

I'm using Python 3.7.4 on IPython 7.7.0 in Spyder 3.7.

Comment: I don't think so. Technically functions are also globals; if you had a function that called another function (that wasn't passed as a parameter), you'd trigger the warning. It's important to remember that global variables aren't always a bad thing. Mutable global state may have its problems, but readonly global variables usually won't be an issue (depending on your needs).

Comment: Don't use global variables, you'll get a warning if you don't pass the proper variable to your functions!

Comment: There are perfectly legitimate every-day use cases for this too, so there's no way to distinguish what you mean from what you don't mean automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. In python, everything is an truly an object, so "globals" would include classes, functions and imported modules too.

However, you can check if a function uses global variables by something like

```py
import inspect, warnings

y = 5

def f(x):
    return x + y

def warn_me(func):
    if inspect.getclosurevars(func).globals:
        warning.warn(f'function {func.__name__} uses global variables')

warn_me(f)
```

For debugging purposes, you could make a script that walks through your files & functions and checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, there are just two mistakes in your code: The module is named `warnings` and you missed an underscore at `func.__name_`.

Comment: Maybe make this a decorator?

Comment: @sinoroc: depends on how you use it. You can use it in a script that walks through all functions of your code

Comment: Even better, yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend avoiding global variables as much as possible. There are some legitimate reasons to use them, but in general there are cleaner ways to achieve the same results.
2. If you conform to best practices, you would write your global variables in upper case. This is then easy to spot the global variables in your code. Additionally a linting tool such as *pylint* would warn you with a message like this in the case of your example: *Constant name "x" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style*.
3. If you have a lot of global variables/constants, you could place them all in a global *dict* `CONFIG = {'MARCO': 'Polo', 'ping': 'pong',}` and pass this object around from function to function.

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but as I said, I'm using Python for data processing where I basically execute a single linear script file with some configuration input. The only other way to do this would be to wrap up everything in a class.

Comment: "*I've been thinking about that, but*", point 1 or point 2? "The only other way to do this would be to wrap up everything in a class" I am not sure how it would help.

Comment: Point 1. Typically I have a few configuration variables and a data source. I read the data, process it, and write it to some file again. When developing those routines I often have to check the data inbetween so I have the dataframe as a global variable to always look at it in the interpreter. The main linear data processing always happens in the main scope and processing code only goes to functions in the end after it's finished. I could wrap up the main line also in a function to reduce the number of global variables though.